# Binding updates to shell component pages delayed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a Shell that has a home page and a settings page.
The settings page makes changes to a singleton service that the home's ViewModel is binded to (MVVM).

I have set up break points on the PropertyChangedEvents of elements on the Home page and they hit as soon as changes are made to the service's properties and their PropertyChanged is executed.

However, upon going back to the home page via the Shell, the page's UI only updates when the page is active and visible. This causes fields to flash when they change. But the breakpoints suggest that they should have updated before.

Is there a way to force refresh the UI before or are there any other alternatives?

For now I have made my view perform a Fade In animation so that changes to the ViewModel don't cause flashing.

Comment: Could you please a basic demo which could reproduce this question so that others could help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Even I have a Xamarin Forms Shell app, and I also had the same issue, So what you can do is, Make the common properties Global as in make those properties in App.xaml.cs and mark them as static.
So when the User changes the property on settings change the App.PropertyName.

Then on the OnApearing method of homepage call a method on the ViewModel say LoadDataValues() and read the App.PropertyName and modify the UI as needed.

What this will do is just before the HomePage appears it will keep the UI of HomePage ready.

Let me know if you have further issues.